# Can i get the right indexes in a sum?

Tags: summation

Do have here 4 examples of sums.
What to fill in for **x and y** to get a general true statement ?
Can MMA assist me to get these answers for x and y?

Sum 1 : $\sum _{k=1}^{n+1} a_k=\sum _{k=1}^n a_k+a_X$

Sum2 : $\sum _{k=n}^{n+1} a_k=X$

Sum3 : $\sum _{k=X}^{2 n} a_k+\sum _{k=1}^n a_k=\sum _{k=1}^Y a_k$

Sum4: $\sum _{k=1}^n a_k-\sum _{k=m}^n a_k=\sum _{k=X}^Y a_k$

Comment: The second one does not make much sense to me. Solve $X$ in terms of what? It already has an expression.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0, thanks, the first sum as you calculated seems to me correct, well done.
 The second sum is almost the same as the first one : `x = Subscript[a, n] + Subscript[a, n + 1`
Difficult to do this sort of math with MMA .

Comment: I did the second one for you as well, since you mentioned that it is difficult to do this kind of stuff in Mathematica. The other two cases follow trivially

Comment: Amazing ,to solve sum 2,  i got here another example what gives true in MMA: `Assuming[n >= 1, FullSimplify[Sum[k, {k, 1, n + 1}] == Sum[k, {k, 1, n}] + (n + 1)` 
Sum 1 and Sum 2 should be then true..

Comment: Good. So it seems that you know how to use `Assumptions` in order to impose conditions. This is what it takes for the other two. There are conditions from mathematics for $X$ and $Y$. Assumptions plus the general framework shown for the first two should be enough...I think

Comment: Sum 1  and sum 2 forms are  built in MMA , but sum 3 is not built in ? (correct answers? x= n and y = 2n )
Is there a way to expand the sum is some terms ?

Comment: This form `Sum[a[[k]], {k, 1, 10}]`  seems to be the same form as `Sum[Subscript[a, k], {k, 1, 10}]` ?

Comment: For sum 3 i think it must be X= 1 and y = 2n+n 
note: in my earlier answer written: x= n , y = 2n , but seems to me make no sense

Comment: For Sum 4: y=n and x= m-1 
This form shall be accepted by MMA and also for Sum 3 , i quess. 
Both earlier answers are changed now

Comment: I believe that the best approach would be for you to work out these examples by hand and understand what the expected result is. Update the OP and start thinking how you can go about it using Mma. I will try to get back to it at some point.

Comment: Yes, i checked also the sums 3 and 4 by using numbers for  1 to 5 for  the serie of natural numbers   
It seems to be correct for boths sum 3 and 4. 
Well, in fact is again proving by complete induction for sum 3 and sum 4.
You can try to do that , but  i am satisfied with the result now

Comment: I did a attempt for Sum 3 :
 `exp[n_] := Sum[a[k], {n, x, 2*n}] + Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}] - 
   Sum[a[k], {k, 1, 2*n + n}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of an extended comment rather than a full answer.

Instead of a `True` statement, you can always subtract and get a `0` or rather a string of `0`s.

An example demonstrating how this works for the first example you gave. We define a function after shifting everything to the LHS

```
exp[n_] := Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n + 1}] - Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}] - aX
```

Take some values for `n`, create a `Table` and solve every time

```
sltn = Solve[Table[exp[n], {n, 0, 10}] == 0] // Flatten
```

> 

```
{a[1] -> aX, a[2] -> aX, a[3] -> aX, a[4] -> aX, a[5] -> aX, 
 a[6] -> aX, a[7] -> aX, a[8] -> aX, a[9] -> aX, a[10] -> aX, 
 a[11] -> aX}
```

Check the above solutions for peace of mind in the following manner

```
Table[exp[n], {n, 0, 10}] /. sltn
```

which gives

> `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

as it should.

Finally, it is not difficult to see from the above that $X$ in the $a_X$ is precisely $n+1$. For $n=0$ it is $1$, then for $n=1$ it is $2$ and so on and so forth. I guess what I am trying to say is that you can observe the arguments in the solutions for $a[i]$ above and do the following simple step

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, n] /. n -> n + 1
```

which gives

> `1 + n`

as it should.

I am hoping that this is a clear explanation on how to go about the rest.

Edit: since it was mentioned in the comments that the second one is difficult, I am showing how to do it below.

Following the logic outlined above, we define

```
expr[n_] := Sum[a[k], {k, n, n + 1}] - xx
```

and we `Solve` for six indicative cases

```
Table[Solve[expr[n] == 0, xx], {n, 0, 5}] // Flatten
```

The answer we get is given by the following:

> 

```
{xx -> a[0] + a[1], xx -> a[1] + a[2], xx -> a[2] + a[3], 
 xx -> a[3] + a[4], xx -> a[4] + a[5], xx -> a[5] + a[6]}
```

And now what we only need to do is to apply `FindSequenceFunction` twice. Once for the argument of the first term in the sum of the above solution `a[0],a[1],...,a[5]` and another one for the second one `a[1],a[2],...,a[6]`

That is we run

```
FindSequenceFunction[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, n] /. n -> n + 1
FindSequenceFunction[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, n] /. n -> n + 1
```

which give

> `n`

and

> `1 + n`

which is actually telling us that

$$X = a_n + a_{n+1}$$

and thus we conclude the proof.